# how can i hide the vscode terminal when opening a file?

Tags: visual-studio-code

i use the following setting so that when i switch to the terminal in vscode, it opens maximized:

```
{
  "workbench.panel.opensMaximized": "always"
}
```

and when i switch to and from the editor via keyboard shortcut, this works great: full size editor and full size terminal.

my problem is when i am looking at the terminal, and switch to a file via the fuzzy finder or clicking on a file path, my terminal is now un-maximized and half-covering the editor. i'd like my view to either be full screen editor or full screen terminal  panel. how can i get it to switch to the file, and completely hide the terminal panel?

Comment: The Keyboard shortcut ^` will show/hide the integrated terminal
It's not the solution you are are looking for, but...

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use Zen mode.